# Small DC motor Heating up!

Tags: motor, dc, fan, cooling

I am just trying to build a small fan to keep my Mac a little cooler from outside.
So I have this little Box Design I made. Now, I'm a total noob at this thing so I need beginner level help here. I've made this circuit, which works great.

What I'm doing is that I'm using the USB outlet to power this motor which is connected to a Fan blade.
There's no resistor in the circuit. The motor is heating up in a use of just 1 minute so I need assistance on what I should do. I've read that Small DC motors can also catch fire if overheated too much.

[image: Also,There's no readings on the motor related to its current and volt input so I don't know what to do. Is there too much current or too much volt? I believe the USB port delivers 5V and 0.5A]

Also, there's no readings on the motor related to its current and voltage input so I don't know what to do. Is there too much current or too much volt? I believe the USB port delivers 5V and 0.5A

Comment: Can you please share the datasheet or the model of the motor with us ?

Comment: Advice: Use a motor that you are sure is rated for the voltage and mechanical load or buy a proper fan or more efficient computer. Anything can catch fire if overheated too much.

Comment: The USB port in general is only good for 100mA until the computer and the attached device have finished negotiations for the higher current. I'd use an external USB supply instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without a datasheet it's really hard for all of us to help you.**

---

I will keep it simple:There are 2 possible reasons for overheating:

1. The motor is not intended for continuous duty operation.
2. The mechanical load is too high for the motor to handle which causes a high current to pass through the motor and heat it up.

---

possible soultion:

smaller fan means a smaller load. So you can try replacing the fan with a smaller one.

try to connect a small resistor is series. you should try and find the ideal value but you could try a value near 10ohm. the resistor will create a voltage drop and the fan will run at a lower voltage than 5V. The fan will run slower ofcourse

---

other solutions:

1. Heatsinking: think of a way to dissipate the heat. using heat sinks, air flow... etc
2. different power source than a USB port.

Answer (score 0):

You may be supplying your dc motor with insufficent voltage which may cause a sitiuation called **stalling**. As your motor starts to spin it produces a **back EMF** that resists the current that being applied to the motor , when dc motor stops due to poor torque (when your motor torque is lower than your load torque) you are practically producing no back EMF and no means to limit the current. In this situation your dc motor is just a low resistance across your voltage source.Which may cause the overheating.I'd check the datasheet of your motor and find the appropriate values to be sure though.